# What is target in tsconfig.json for?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, transpiler

What does `target` in `tsconfig.json` signify?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": 
  {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "classic",
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom",  "es2017" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

> I am quite new to Typescript. What does Target in tsconfig.json signify?

`target` signifies *which target of JavaScript should be emitted from the given TypeScript*. Examples:

## `target:es5`

`()=>null` will become `function(){return null}` as ES5 doesn't have arrow functions.

## `target:es6`

`()=>null` will become `()=>null` as ES6 has arrow functions.

## More

I also made a quick [video on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kgi1j8Zp6b0) .

Comment: do i still need babel if i target es5
also my typescript code contains async and await, will that compile if i give target as es5?

Comment: Don't need babel for that 

Comment: I was using `es5` but it interprets destructuring `[...arr].map` as `arr.slice().map`, which breaks for array-like object that don't have `slice`. When I target es6, it starts working in my browser, but will it work for everyone?

Comment: @Qwerty No, it will not. For example, it will not work in Internet Explorer 11, since that doesn't support es6 and doesn't have the .map function.  Even if you target es5, it STILL will not work in Internet Explorer, because it's not the transpiler's job to add polyfills.  You'd still need to add a polyfill if you wanted to support non-es6 browsers.

Comment: @pabrams so IE11 does not even support all of ES5?

Comment: @Qwerty Well, what I'm saying is that Typescript transpilation doesn't polyfill missing methods for you, it only takes care of the syntax.  This thread explains it fairly well:  https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/issues/166

Comment: If you're building a library for other web apps to use then their bundler should polyfill these.

Answer (score 14):

Target changes the JavaScript version you are compiling to.

The options are available at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

In the spirit of trying to better understand how the target flag changes my code I compiled some test code to each of the different versions to have a better understanding of the differences.

https://github.com/aizatto/typescript-playground/tree/master/dist/test-async-main

I'm also keeping notes of what I should be targeting depending on what environment I am looking at

https://www.aizatto.com/notes/typescript

Answer (score 3):

If your target is `es2017` , that's the latest version with new library references to shared memory and string. Changing your target means changing the libraries with which your code compiles. If you want to keep the target a low version while supporting libraries referenced by higher versions, you may add the required library to the `"lib"` in `tsconfig.json`.

To know more about the libraries referenced in different versions, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956326/typescript-tsconfig-compileroptions-es2017-target-and-lib) answer.