# Angular ng build with minimum number of files ? (supporting only Chrome is also fine)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8

When I build my angular project i see

`main-es5.js` and `main-es2015.js`  both files. I just want to support only Chrome browser how can I turn off building the old js files I want minimum number of files on Build.

My Build also runs twice since I upgraded to 8

Note

> Build time has significantly increased and i get the warning WARNING
>   in budgets, maximum exceeded for initial.

This is my **Angular.json** File

```
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "none",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "extractCss": false,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "showCircularDependencies": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": false,
      "statsJson": false,
      "progress": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
```

**browserlist file**

```
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist

> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

**Edit**: Raised feature request on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14679#issue-452638524)

Comment: This depends on browserslist. It's all explained in the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading

Comment: Define "Modern Browsers"? Do you want it to compile to ES6 instead of ES5?

Comment: edited my question, how can I get a minimum build for only Chrome latest versions, basically i want least amount of files on build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [@clydin](https://github.com/clydin) 's comment on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14679)

```
**browserlist** 
last 2 Chrome versions
```

https://browserl.ist/?q=last+2+Chrome+versions

Creates a minimal chrome only ES2015+ build

Answer (score 3):

Inside tsconfig.json there is target : "es2015" change target to "es5" you will get build like angular 7 application.

Comment: what is the difference between `es5` and `es2015`

Comment: Thanks but If i change to `es5` doesn't that mean to support for old browsers ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct it will not support old(legacy) browsers.

Comment: But it's all depends on your code as well.. if you use flex then it will not support below IE 10 etc.

Comment: No, that's not what i meant, See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42429053/5724889 es5 will just covert to old code